# Copy a range with an input box and paste on a fixed range on a specific sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I have this code which allows me to a copy a customized range and paste that range on a specified sheet. However I am unable to do so when inserting a fixed range for that specified sheet. For example the code below pastes link to sheet 2 but I want it to be able to paste link to Range(B2:N5) of Sheet 2. How can this be done? Some help would be very much appreciated!

```
Sub WorkingDuoFunctionCode()
    Dim rng As Range, inp As Range
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set inp = Selection
    inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        rng.Parent.Activate
        rng.Select
        inp.Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Link:=True
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorkingDuoFunctionCode()

Dim rng As Range, inp As Range

On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Nothing
Set inp = Selection
inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37

Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
Else
    rng.Parent.Activate
    inp.Copy
    Sheets(2).Range(rng.Address).Value = inp.Value
End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

OR

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorkingDuoFunctionCode()

Dim rng As Range, inp As Range

On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Nothing
Set inp = Selection
inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37

Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
Else
    rng.Parent.Activate
    inp.Copy
    Sheets(2).Range("B2:N5").Value = inp.Value
End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

But this way something becomes useless - you only need 2 ranges for copy - paste and now you get 3 - the selection, the range from the input box and the hardcoded  B2:N5. Anyway, you know better.

Comment: Hi sorry, but it does not state the fixed range i want to paste the selected data (Range(B2:N5))

Comment: Hi, just select the fixed range in the input box and you go.

Comment: hi it works after i made some edits, how do i incorporate paste link in this code?

Comment: Hi Niva, what is a paste link? Actually the second version of the code does the copy and the paste without a reason - the real copying is done in the line Sheet(2).Range("B2:N5").Value = inp.Value. The lines inp.Copy is little useless, but I have used your code as a sample to step on, so you can grasp it better.

Comment: yes i have made amendments as this code didnt work actually! I will update the edited one

Comment: and paste link is a paste option which links cells. It usually one of the paste special options on excel